# Web page isn't showing the ages of each person

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

1 month into javascript now and I am working on my first self-made project: the birthday info page. The last statement 
`$("ul[class='dad']").append("<p>" + dadAge + "</p");` 
is not showing the difference between todays year (2016) and his date of birth in his text. Everything else works fine, but its as if that code is invalid. Or is it? Also if anyone knows any shorter ways to writing this code that would be great. This is the best way that came up in my head on this code.

```
birthdayStyle();
calculateDaysUntilBirthday();

// important_dates.html  page
function birthdayStyle() {
    $("document").ready(function() {
        //$("*").css("color","white");
        $("h2.title").css('font-size', '25px');
        $("h2.title").css('color', 'black');
        $("h3.h3birthday").addClass("h3BdayStyle");
        $("ul.person").addClass('personStyle');
        $("li.birthdate").addClass('birthDateStyle');

    })
};

function calculateDaysUntilBirthday () {
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    var todaysYear = todaysDate.getFullYear();
    var dob = {dad: "1958", mom: '1962', kathy: '1980', jeremy: '1985', chris: '1990', matthew: '1993'}
    var dadAge = dob.dad - dad;
    var momAge = dob.mom - mom;
    var kathyAge = dob.kathy - kathy;
    var jeremyAge = dob.jeremy - jeremy;
    var chrisAge = dob.chris - chris;
    var matthewAge = dob.matthew - matthew;
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $("ul[class='person']").append("<p>" + dadAge + "</p");
    })
}
```

Comment: What is happening instead of the desired behavior?  And are there any console errors when you run your code?

Comment: Where are the `dad`, `mom` etc variables coming from?

Comment: `var dadAge = dob.dad - dad;` try changing to -> `var dadAge =  todaysYear - dob.dad`,.. Btw.. this still is not a great way to check age, as of course people are born during the year :)  IOW: To work out peoples ages, you need the Day/Month & Year,. not just year.